# Bash csh Loop through 2 list

Tags: bash, csh

In csh or any other mac friendly script language, I would like to run some form of a loop that reads through 2 lists. Need a bit of help with the syntax.

For example:

```
variable1 = (1, 2, 3, 4, ...)
variable2 = (one, two, three, four, ...)

Foreach number ($variable1)

echo  "{$variable1} equals {$variable2}"

end
```

When I try, the second `variable2` is not recognized within the loop.

Comment: bash and csh are **completely** different shells. Ask about one or the other, not both at the same time.

Comment: (as an example of why a "question" that actually has multiple questions embedded is frowned on here -- right now you have a bash answer and a csh answer; each is individually correct, but this means you can't select a single "accepted" answer to your question!)

Comment: Aside: http://web.mit.edu/ghudson/info/csh.whynot; http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

variable1=(1 2 3 4) 
variable2=(one two three four)

for ((i=0;i<${#variable1[@]};i++)); do
  echo "${variable1[$i]} equals ${variable2[$i]}"
done
```

Output:

```
1 equals one
2 equals two
3 equals three
4 equals four
```

Comment: This works in this case, because variable1 is a list of indexes, but it doesn't work in the general case of comparing two arrays of items `variable1=(alpha bravo charlie delta)` `variable2=(alpha beta gamma delta)`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
#! /bin/csh
set variable1 = (1 2 3 4) 
set variable2 = (one two three four)
set i = 1
foreach x ( $variable1 )
    echo "$x equals $variable2[$i]"
    @ i = $i + 1
end
```

The result is:

```
1 equals one
2 equals two
3 equals three
4 equals four
```

Comment: You don't need echo, like: `foreach x ( \`echo $variable1\` )`.  This will work just as well `foreach x ( $variable1 )`